# CDate and IsDate not recognizing "dd.mm.yyyy" date format

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

On server 2012R2, IIS8, test.asp

```
<%=IsDate("16.07.2014")%> returns False
<%=IsDate("16/07/2014")%> returns True
<%=IsDate("16-07-2014")%> returns True
<%=IsDate("16,07,2014")%> returns True
<%=IsDate("16 07 2014")%> returns True
```

I need the first format of course. The CDate function does not work on first date either.

Has it something to do with regional settings? I have tried to change the user profile regional settings. then I copied My current settings to welcome screen and system accounts but it did not help.

Comment: This has been asked numerous times before. Just search.

Comment: @Lankymart - Could you show me where please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SetLocale`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232158/en-us) allows an ad-hoc specification of the script's behaviour:

```
>> WScript.Echo CStr(IsDate("16.07.2014"))
>>
False
>> SetLocale "de-de"
>> WScript.Echo CStr(IsDate("16.07.2014"))
>>
True
```

**Update wrt comment:**

This (hopefully) better sample

```
>> ol = GetLocale()
>> WScript.Echo 0, ol
>> SetLocale "en-us"
>> WScript.Echo 1, GetLocale()
>> WScript.Echo 2, CStr(IsDate("16.07.2014"))
>> SetLocale "cs-cz"
>> WScript.Echo 3, GetLocale()
>> WScript.Echo 4, CStr(IsDate("16.07.2014"))
>> SetLocale ol
>> WScript.Echo 5, GetLocale()
>>
0 1033
1 1033
2 False
3 1029
4 True
5 1033
```

demonstrates

1. that "cs-cz" should work
2. how to save/restore the current locale

Comment: It works for me. I have figured out that here, in Czech Republic, we actually have dd.mm.yyyy format but the SetLocale "cs-cz" makes these functions failing on this format. I have to use german locale instead.

Comment: @Combinatix - please see update. "cs-cz" 'not working' for *you* may indicate a mis-configuration of your server.